# how to change properties of controls (for eg: textview) of layout included in another layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, properties

i have a very basic and simple question..
i have created a layout which contains five textviews..
as given below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bluepatch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bluepatch" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sunshineinfinitylogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/sunshineinfinitylogo" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Floorplan"
            android:textColor="#DDC93D" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="---------------------------------"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Ground FloorPlan"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="1ST TO 3RD PODIUM LEVEL PLAN"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="4TH PODIUM LEVEL PLAN"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="8, 13, 18, 23 floorplans"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Layout FloorPlan"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Typical floorplans"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

now i am including this particular layout in five different layouts..
now my question is when i include this layout along with i want to make changes to particular textview,,  for eg: changing color of text in textview with id text1 from white to yellow..
how can i do this???

Answer (score 0):

Attach an id attribute to each included layout. Then find this view by `findViewById` method passing the attached id and use `findViewById` method of the found view to change the attribute of particular `TextView`.

Comment: i guess the way you are suggesting is to do it by code in oncreate method bt can i do it in xml itself while creating a new xml which includes this particular layout.. and can u also plz check this question [link to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116974/how-to-load-activity-layout-in-android-while-the-video-is-playing-in-background) if possible thank you.

Comment: @user2454989 I don't think it's possible through xml only.